# TTTableSubtitleItem does not show defaultImage when scrolling

Tags: image, three20, default

I have a TTTableSubtitleItem to display a simple list of people. I show the person's avatar with an empty avatar icon as the defaultImage. When the page first loads, the empty avatar is displayed correctly as a placeholder until the web image is done loading. However, when i scroll down the list, instead of displaying the defaultImage for the new rows, its now displaying the previously loaded web images instead. This is especially problematic on slower connections since it will appear that the wrong person's avatar is being displayed. any suggestions?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to download the [latest three20 development branch](https://github.com/facebook/three20/tarball/development).

there was a bug related to issue and I think it was already fixed in it. https://github.com/facebook/three20/pull/483